# TimePicker inside a Div with content reloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

OK, first question so be gentle :)
I'm working on a HTML/PHP form that uses some time pickers.
I have several DIVs that I'm changing the display mode (block/none) to hide and unhide.
Some of the Divs use a jQuery time picker that I found with a bit of Googling.

Here is one of the Divs where the time picker works:

```
<div class="Schedule" style="display: none;" id="schedule">
    <br />
    <Strong>Schedule Settings</Strong>
    <br /><br />
            Start Time: <br /><input class="timepicker" type="text" id="schedstartpicker" name="schedstartpicker" size="30" disabled><br /><br />
            End Time: <br /><input class="timepicker" type="text" id="schedendpicker" name="schedendpicker" size="30" disabled><br /><br />
    <br /><br />
    <br />
</div>
```

These input fields are enabled later using a button.
They are turned into time picker fields using the following

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#schedstartpicker').timepicker();
    $('#schedendpicker').timepicker();

    $('#starttimepicker').timepicker();
    $('#endtimepicker').timepicker();
});
```

Note that there are also two extra time pickers here. These are in a different DIV. Below is a simplified version of the div content:

```
<div class="recovery" id="recovery" style="display: none;">
    <table border=0 style='font-size:small' width=622px>

        <tr>
                        <td>
                                        <b>Start Time</b>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                                        <input type="text" id="starttimepicker" name="starttimepicker" size="30" value="9HC7kXRXpz">
                        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
                        <td>
                                        <b>End Time</b>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                                        <input type="text" id="endtimepicker" name="endtimepicker" size="30" value="fSpFW77Xkw">
                        </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
```

Now... here comes the issue.
Both of these DIVs are loaded with the page. Both are hidden to begin with.
When the page is loaded, all 4 of the time pickers work.

Later on, I using Javascript to take the content of the "recovery" div, replace the bits of placeholder (9HC7kXRXpz & fSpFW77Xkw) text with other data, and then put the modified text back into the DIV.

This is done like so:

```
function refill_recovery(data1,data2) {

    var recovery = document.getElementById("recovery").innerHTML;

    var recovery=recovery.replace("9HC7kXRXpz",data1);
    var recovery=recovery.replace("fSpFW77Xkw",data2)

            document.getElementById("recovery").innerHTML = recovery;

}
```

This is all working quite well and I'm happy with it.
However, when the updated text is placed back into the Div, the time pickers are lost.

I have tried to use another function called after the Div is updated, and set them as time pickers again, but can't get it to work. Added the window alert so I knew for sure that the function was running.

```
function settimepickers() {
    $('#starttimepicker').timepicker();
    $('#endtimepicker').timepicker();
    window.alert("TIME PICKERS SHOULD BE SET");
}
```

I'm calling functions to enable and disabled the Divs like this:

```
onclick="refill_recovery('data1','data2'); toggle_visibility('recovery'); settimepickers();"
```

Kinda lost on this one so any idea on how I could re-set them as time pickers would be great.

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: I should also add that for the "recovery" div I have tried to set the class on the input boxes as with the first div, but no change

Comment: any chance you have duplicate elements in your dom with the same id ('#starttimepicker')?

Comment: @JanR no, there are no duplicate elements... that was the first thing I made sure of :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting `innerHTML` will wipe away the DOM you had and replace it.

Instead, update those values using the DOM:

```
function refill_recovery(data1, data2)
  $('#starttimepicker').val(data1);
  $('#endtimepicker').val(data2);
}
```

This will preserve everything, and just update the values.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply! Unfortunately it's nearly the end of my shift, so I will give that a go next time I'm working and update with whether it works or not

Answer (score 1):

I believe since you are replacing the html you will need to call your ready function to activate the datepickers again (I mean these lines):

```
$('#schedstartpicker').timepicker();
$('#schedendpicker').timepicker();

$('#starttimepicker').timepicker();
$('#endtimepicker').timepicker();
```

While creating this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/j8N6PKBiqq0AJriSAjuU?p=preview), I figured out you've put disabled in your inputs which makes them not working even after calling `.timepicker()` after replacing the html.

Comment: OP is already doing this by calling settimepickers() which does not seem to resolve the issue

Comment: You don't need to be aggresive @JanR, this code will definitely work, it is just the matter of checking whether those div's are still there after replace or not, do you want me to create a plunkr for you?

Comment: Not being aggressive, just letting you know that if you read the whole question you can see that the OP is already resetting the timepicker() by calling the function settimepickers()

Comment: But feel free to create a plunkr :)

Comment: There you go @JanR : https://plnkr.co/edit/j8N6PKBiqq0AJriSAjuU?p=preview and please get your vote back

Comment: Thanks for that, not sure why this doesn't work for the OP. unfortunately I can't undo  my vote until the answer is edited.